# What is the methods of debuging Web Application based on JSF technology?

Tags: debugging, jsf

I'm new in JSF ,and I want method to trace the problem that happen in the web application , away from Web Application Server that doesn't provide useful information in most cases.
any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

For the server side: All modern IDEs have debuggers integrated. Use them to debug problems on the server side.

For the client side: Use the developer tools of modern browsers. Chrome has a good one integrated. For Firefox there is a plugin called Firebug (heard it is integrated in Firefox 4.0).